# Allow only listing of resources using Kubernetes RBAC

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, rbac

I want to allow **only** listing of resources and not the manifest content.

Example,

```
NAME                                 READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
airflow-redis-0                      1/1     Running   0          32h
airflow-postgresql-0                 1/1     Running   0          32h
airflow-scheduler-9416ddfd6f-n7jcr   2/2     Running   0          32h
airflow-webserver-9bf7f3c95c-kf1fx   1/1     Running   0          32h
airflow-worker-0                     2/2     Running   0          4h8m
```

With `GET` permission users can see the manifest of the pod individually. For example, `kubectl describe pod airflow-worker-0 -n airflow`

Similarly, with `LIST` permission users can see the manifest of all the pods with commands like - `kubectl get pod --output=json`

Is it possible to restrict manifest access and just allow the listing of resources in K8 RBAC?

Comment: You want to list objects without getting full object content? As you figured out list would return full objects _and it doesn't call another get request_

Comment: And disabling describe has nothing to do with list permission. Describe calls get.

Comment: @reith I edited the question to make it clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Showing only a listing of resources and not the object content is not possible by using any of the RBAC request verbs.

`list` can't be used. It provides the listing but will also allow accessing full object content.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to restrict users to **only** list resources, you should create a role with *get* verb.
[Role example](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/#role-example) in official documentations shows it quite well

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: Role
metadata:
  namespace: default
  name: pod-reader
rules:
- apiGroups: [""] # "" indicates the core API group
  resources: ["pods"]
  verbs: ["get", "watch", "list"]
```

So, to restrict to e.g. only `get pods` - change `verbs` to

```
verbs: ["get"]
```

If you want to also allow listing e.g. *deployments* - change `resources` to

```
resources: ["pods", "deployments"]
```

---

As you already noticed, `list` gives permission to full object content.

Comment: @WytrzymałyWiktor I edited the question to make it clear. With some exploration, I don't think it's possible to just allow listing and block manifest.